# Jar creation using ant produces wrong output

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am using ant to create a jar for a project.

here is the target

```
<jar destfile="artifacts/my-jar-file.jar" basedir=".">
    <include name="bin/**" />
</jar>
```

The jar is getting created but it creates the packages as :

bin.com.aryasindhu.testjar.  ...

But I don't need the bin appended before the package.

Please suggest me what I need to change in the jar creation target.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<jar destfile="artifacts/my-jar-file.jar" basedir="./bin">
    <include name="*/**" />
</jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got my answer.

Here is the change in the target that I am using now :

```
<jar destfile="artifacts/my-jar-file.jar">
     <fileset dir="bin" includes="**/*.class" />
</jar>
```